# Meaning of I(I())

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, most-vexing-parse

Sample code:

```
typedef int I;
struct X{ X(int); };

int main()
{
    int(int());
    X(X());
    I(I());
}
```

The line `int(int());` is an expression using functional cast notation - it's a temporary `int` initialized with a value-initialized `int`.

The line `X(X());` is a declaration of a function named `X` taking no arguments returning struct `X`.

My question is: what is the meaning of `I(I())` here?  And what rules in the standard determine the difference in meaning between these three cases?

Comment: The `typedef int I` makes `I` behave *exactly* like `int`.  It merely assigns another name.  Therefore the line `I(I())` and `int(int())` have the exact same meaning.  For more on `typedef` see [[dcl.typedef](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.typedef)].

Comment: According to gcc/clang, it is as for `X`, a declaration of function `I` returning `int`.

Comment: all 3 are function decls

Comment: @Sopel: False. As it is clearly stated in the question, the first one is NOT a function declaration. The fact that `int` is a keyword makes a critical difference in the first case.

Comment: whoops, sorry, there are no names, you're right

Comment: I would say that `int` is not a valid name for function contrary to `X`/`I`.

Answer (score 3):

The rule says that if a construct is ambiguously syntax for either a declaration, or a statement, then it is considered to be a declaration.

> [stmt.ambig] 1 There is an ambiguity in the grammar involving expression-statements and declarations: An expression-
>   statement with a function-style explicit type conversion (5.2.3) as its leftmost subexpression can be indis-
>   tinguishable from a declaration where the first declarator starts with a (. In those cases the statement is a
>   declaration.

`X(X());` is ambiguous, because it could be either a cast, or a function declaration, so it is considered to be a declaration.

`int(int());` cannot be a function declaration, because `int`, being a keyword, is not a valid name for a function. So, there is no ambiguity, it is a cast.

Likewise, `I(I());` cannot be a function declaration, because although not a keyword, `I` is not a valid name either because it would redeclare the type `I` as a function, which is not allowed, so it is a cast.

Comment: What are you saying `I(I());` means then exactly?

Comment: @M.M As I understand the rules, It is a functional cast, and value initialized temporary, as is `int(int())`.

Comment: This *might* be the rule that disallows re-definition of a typedef: `A name declared with the typedef specifier becomes a typedef-name. Within the scope of its declaration,typedef-name is syntactically equivalent to a keyword and ...`. Keywords may not be re-defined... but this seems a bit vague.

Comment: The rule is this one: http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope.declarative#4
It only applies if the typedef is in the same declarative region as the other declaration. Not if one of them is in a nested scope. The purpose of this rule is to disallow this kind of silliness as much as possible, only retaining compatibility with C (which, e.g., has both a function and a struct named `stat`)